# Angular 2/4/5 Inside ASP.NET WebForm application

Tags: webforms, angular5

Right now we have a Asp.Net web form application  which is hosted in IIS.

How can I add my angular-5 script files inside the existing Application in IIS?

And if so, How my angular routing will work?

NOTE: Here I don't want to host my Angular project separately inside the IIS.

Let me know in case the question is not understandable fully. I can give the example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very broad question. Would you be able to make the question more specific?

Comment: Currently I have the nav bar in my web forms. Home,About,Contact

Each tab associated with Home.aspx, About.aspx and so on

On other side, I have Angular page ready for Contact tab and I want to integrate it within Contact.aspx

I have some idea how to acehieve that like, we have to add those bundle script files from angular into web forms and insert the 

main selector tag <app-root></app-root>

I added all scripts into WebForm and inside the Contact.aspx page I deleted everything and just added the  <app-root></app-root>

But somehow it is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit late, but I recently faced a similar problem, and I wanted to share it in case anyone else stumbles with the same problem. Even if it would have be preferable to host it in some other way, we needed to integrate a new Angular application with an existing WebForms one.

To give the control of the router to angular, declare the next function in Global.asax

```
Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.MapPageRoute("MyRouteName", "MyAppPath/{*path}", "~/MyAppAspx.aspx")
    routes.MapPageRoute("MyRouteName2", "MyAppPath2/{*path}", "~/MyAppAspx2.aspx")
    'And so on
End Sub
```

This will make webforms redirect all requests to "myhost/MyAppPath/" to the provided aspx, so that angular can take care of the routing.

Then you must just create the required aspx and provide there the needed scripts in the order they appear in the generated index.html.